# How to Create DB links in Postgres for Virtual Columns in a table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, dblink

I have an Oracle Query as follows that uses a dblink,

```
SELECT * FROM  SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES WHERE ( PRODUCT_TYPE) IN 
(SELECT PRODUCT_TYPE FROM SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES
MINUS
SELECT PRODUCT_TYPE FROM SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES@FPORDDEV);
```

Now I converted it to Postgres using the dblink as follows,

```
SELECT * FROM  SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES WHERE (PRODUCT_TYPE) IN 
(SELECT PRODUCT_TYPE FROM SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES
EXCEPT 
SELECT * from dblink 
('dbname=NTE5OFF port=5432 host=xxxxx 
  user=yyyyy password=zzzzz','SELECT PRODUCT_TYPE FROM 
  SSP2_PCAT.PRODUCT_TYPES')
as t (PRODUCT_TYPE character varying(60)) );
```

Now this is working absolutely Fine!

Now, how can I convert the below same Oracle sql with virtual column as below,

```
SELECT 'ITO' FRM, SALES_CD, SALES_CODE_DESC, ACTIVE_IND
FROM SSP2_PCAT.ACCT_LVL_SALES_CDS
EXCEPT 
SELECT 'ITO' FRM, SALES_CD, SALES_CODE_DESC, ACTIVE_IND
FROM SSP2_PCAT.ACCT_LVL_SALES_CDS@FPORDDEV;
```

I tried the code in Postgres as follows, but obviously its throwing an error given the virtual column,

```
SELECT 'ITO' FRM, SALES_CD, SALES_CODE_DESC, ACTIVE_IND FROM 
SSP2_PCAT.ACCT_LVL_SALES_CDS
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM dblink 
('dbname=NTE5OFF port=5432 host=xxxxx 
user=yyyyy password=zzzzz', 
'SELECT FRM, SALES_CD, SALES_CODE_DESC, ACTIVE_IND FROM 
SSP2_PCAT.ACCT_LVL_SALES_CDS')
as t ( FRM varchar,
   sales_cd character varying(15),
       sales_code_desc character varying(150),
       active_ind character varying(3) ) );
```

Can someone please let me know, if I'm missing anything here?

Comment: Please bear in mind that you have cut and pasted your AWS connection details into your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to

```
SELECT 'ITO' FRM ...
```

in the dblink query, but since it is in a string, you'll have to double the single quotes to escape them:

```
'SELECT ''ITO'' FRM ...'
```

But it would be much simpler to use foreign tables with postgres_fdw.

Comment: Thank You Sirr, not sure how I missed it,

Thanks everyone for your time for looking into this.,,!!!